# sublime text 2 php tidy

Tags: php, formatting, sublimetext2

I installed the phptidy plugin for Sublime Text 2 and tried to use it to clean up some ugly code like

```
$tdt="<td class=\"tit2\" ";
    $linka='<a href="products.php?action=history5&item=';

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
        {   extract($row);
```

But after running Php Tidy, a console flashed and it seems to have edited the entire file, but nothing actually changed. Does anyone know if the plugin below still works?

https://github.com/welovewordpress/SublimePhpTidy

Comment: I just installed that plugin and tested it with the same code you gave above (also wrapping it in <?php ?> tags) and it worked for me.

Comment: I also checked to see if being on the wrong syntax view would cause an error and it did not. The only thing that did cause it to not work was not having it wrapped in the php tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Console would open and close too fast to read what was going on.

Step 1: I opened up the Sublime Console (CTRL + ` on Windows)

Step 2: Reading the output gave me the hint. PhpTidy relies on php.exe being installed on your machine (duh)

This last step might seem obvious, but I was networked into another computer where the code lived and coding it over the wire. As such, when I ran phpTidy on my local machine, it failed due to the lack of php itself.

Answer (score 0):

At first you must add the `<?php ?>` to beginning and end of your PHP file.

If you based-on Win, see the output of PHPTidy Processes on the 'Ctrl+`' Console.

There is a tip:

`PhpTidy: calling php.exe -v returned: 0`.

If it returns 1, maybe 'php.exe' wasn't found, add the path of your ‘php.exe’ to ENV.

Comment: could you plz tell me how to add the path of php.exe to ENV

thnks